# Detecting if a CSS3 property is doable using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I'm wondering if I can figure out if a CSS3 property is doable in user's web browser

like:

```
if($('#element').css('-moz-transform', 'rotateX(180deg')){ //Do something }
```

Above example does not work. If it is not possible how do I detect the browser using javascript? For example, webkit browser like Chrome and Safari or Mozilla browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not JQuery, but my suggestion would be to use the [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) Javascript library.

It does exactly what you're asking, being able to detect support for a wide range of browser features which may or may not be available in various browsers, including CSS 2D transforms.

It adds a range of classes to your `<body>` element so you can set CSS styles according to feature support, and it also makes available a Javascript object with all the feature support flags, which you can query at any point.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible using [**`getComputedStyle`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3awindow.getComputedStyle) but it's far easier to use a plugin that unifies all the browser differences in CSS3. One good plugin is the [**jQuery transform plugin**](https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transform.js/blob/master/README.md)